# How to find the time complexity of thus algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

*Hi, we have just started to cover this topic so I'm not really sure what to do here and the examples in the book are not helping me.
The program is:

```
public static Stack<Queue<Integer>> qq(Stack<Queue<Integer>> q1) 
    {
        Stack<Queue<Integer>>copy=new Stack<Queue<Integer>>(); // 1
        Stack<Queue<Integer>>copy1=new Stack<Queue<Integer>>(); // 1
        while(!q1.isEmpty()) // n+1
            copy.push(q1.pop()); // n
        while(!copy.isEmpty()) // n+1
        {
            q1.push(copy.top()); // n
            copy1.push(copy.pop()); // n
        }
        while(!copy1.isEmpty()) // n+1
        {
            Queue<Integer>q=new Queue<Integer>(); // n
            copy.push(q); // n
            int n1=copy1.top().remove(); // n
            while (!copy1.top().isEmpty()==true)
            {
                for (int i=n1+1;i<copy1.top().head();i++)
                    copy.top().insert(i);
                n1=copy1.top().remove();
            }
            copy1.pop(); // n
        }
        while(!copy.isEmpty()) // n+1
            copy1.push(copy.pop()); // n
        return copy1; // 1
```

If the complexity is n+1 for example, our teacher would like us to leave it that way and not simplify to n.

I am not sure how to calculate the complexity where I didn't write it, I think the rest is correct. Could anyone explain that to me? 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity depends, how much time your program/code is taking to execute.
Roughly(Asymptotically) 
if your code doesn't have any loop then it takes constant time i.e. O(1)
if your code has loop and it's running for n time then your program time complexity is O(n)

In this case, your code is running n+1 times, so you can conclude that, time complexity of your program is O(n) - Asymptotically.